# Multi Auth going to different blades. How can i do that?

Tags: laravel

[Login Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNFA6.png)I have my home.blade.php and my admin.blade.php
The problem is that the validation is occuring inside the home.blade.php
My question is, how can I do the validation in the login button?

[web.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9rfp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and paste my code in your `LoginController.php` and `RegisterController.php`:

```
  public function redirectTo(){
   // Check if user is Admin
    if(auth()->user()->isAdmin) // if IsAdmin == 1 user is an Admin
      {
        return '/admin';
      } 
     else // if IsAdmin != 1 user is not an Admin
     {
        return '/home';
     }
   }
```

Also you have to comment this property on both controllers :
`// protected $redirectTo = '/home';`

Comment: @PedroPires Good !!!! I will appreciate a vote up if you feel that my answer was useful to you. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a inline if in a extends blade syntax to extend deferents layouts depending on the role like this:

```
@extends((auth()->user()->hasRole('Admin')) ? 'layouts.admin' : 'layouts.home')
```

or override the `redirectTo()` function in your `LoginController.php` and `RegisterController.php` like this example:

```
public function redirectTo(){

// User role
 $role = Auth::user()->role->name;
// If your using 'spatie/laravel-permission' you can do something like this
 $role = auth()->user()->getRoleNames()->first();

// Check user role
 switch ($role) {
    case 'Admin':
            return '/admin-home';
        break;
    case 'Manager':
            return '/projects';
        break; 
    default:
            return '/home'; 
        break;
 }
}
```

Also you have to remove this property on both controllers :

`protected $redirectTo = '/home';`

Comment: It stills doesn't work, Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: When it say `'admin.blade.php' ` and `'home.blade.php'` you have to put the actual route ex:`'/home-admin'` and `'/home'` let me know if works.

Comment: @PedroPires I just fixed my response, let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Is there anyway to send you a printscreen of my code?

Comment: In the role-> which one do I use?
I only have a IsAdmin in my db if IsAdmin == 1, user is admin otherwise, the user is a normal user
Then I have a home.blade.php and a admin.blade.php

Comment: You can do something like this `return (auth()->user()->IsAdmin) ? '/admin' : '/home';` instead, you have to declare the routes on your routes/web.php : `Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');   Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@admin');`

Comment: Still not working, I don't know really what to do about this, The user works, but the admin doesn't

Comment: It worked for me, take a look to https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission library for roles.Did you check in your database that the IsAdmin attribute is working ??.

Comment: @PedroPires can you show me your `redirectTo()` function? on `LoginController.php`

Comment: `public function redirectTo(){

        return (auth()->user()->IsAdmin) ? '/admin' : '/home';
    }   `

Comment: The api, channels, console and web?

Comment: Is there any way to contact you via email or something? It would be much more easier

Comment: You can put a screen shoot of your  `LoginController.php` and `web.php` that will help.

Comment: I send it to where?

Comment: Ok that looks ok,  now let me see your `LoginController.php`.

Comment: The login controller is there, at the beginning of the question.

Comment: Everything  looks fine.Can you do a `dd(auth()->user()->isAdmin);` to see what it returns, and upload the screen shot.

Comment: Just for testing purposes in `web.php` file remove `->middleware('admin')`.

Comment: Where do I do the dd(auth()->user()->isAdmin);?

Comment: Witthout the middleware condition, both logins are going to the normal user's page

Comment: @PedroPires in your `LoginController.php` right before the `switch`.

Comment: The `switch`? Sorry, but I'm kinda a noob in all of this.

Comment: Before the `return` my bad.

Comment: Which one? I have 3 returns in the login controller, should I do a return dd(auth()->user()->IsAdmin) ? '/admin' : '/home'; ???

Comment: No, just before the the `return`, that will stop the program from executing and will show the value of `IsAdmin` in that moment.I want to know that to see if the boolean is working property, I have tried the code I suggested  in my project  and works as expected.

Comment: The IsAdmin is doing right, when the user is admin it shows 1 and user shows 0

Comment: I just want to do the auth like If the IsAdmin == 0, user is a normal user
If IsAdmin == 1, user is an admin.

Comment: @PedroPires copy and paste the code on my new answer.